# RadioButton doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have a slight problem using RadioButtons ...

In my app I've dropdown list view where I can select several items and two radio buttons which defines what values app uses.

Here's the problem. If I select first item in dropdown list I can choose between left and right radio button and that works perfectly, but if I choose right radio button and then choose other item from dropdown list app takes values of left radio button not second.

Here's my code of selecting items and choosing between radio buttons.

```
//Setting clickListener on earlierEnrollmentRadioButton
    earlierEnrolmentRB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            earlierRadioButtonChecked();
        }
    });

    //Setting clickListener on laterEnrollmentRadioButton
    laterEnrolmentRB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            laterRadioButtonChecked();
        }
    });



    //Initialization of list of courses for Spinner
    final String[] courseArray = new String[4];
    {
        courseArray[0] = getString(R.string.undergraduate_man);
        courseArray[1] = getString(R.string.undergraduate_traf);
        courseArray[2] = getString(R.string.undergraduate_admin);
        courseArray[3] = getString(R.string.graduate_man);
    }

    //Creating ArrayAdapter of list of courses
    final ArrayAdapter courseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, courseArray);
    //Setting list type
    courseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    //Setting adapter to courses Spinner
    courses.setAdapter(courseAdapter);

    //Creating listener for selecting specific item from @courseArray
    courses.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int pos, long id) {

            //Getting item from Spinner
            cors = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            if (cors.equals(courseArray[0])) {
                laterRadioButtonChecked();
                fullScholar = 6000.0;
            } else if (cors.equals(courseArray[1])) {
                laterRadioButtonChecked();
                fullScholar = 7500.0;
            } else if (cors.equals(courseArray[2])) {
                laterRadioButtonChecked();
                fullScholar = 6000.0;
            } else if (cors.equals(courseArray[3])) {
                laterRadioButtonChecked();
                fullScholar = 6000.0;
            } else {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    });
}

//This method calls values of enrollment before 2014/2015
public void earlierRadioButtonChecked() {
    if(cors.equals(getString(R.string.undergraduate_traf))) {
        ectsPriceText.setText("150.00 kn");
        price = 150;
    } else {
        ectsPriceText.setText("100.00 kn");
        price = 100;
    }
}

//This method calls values of enrollment after 2014/2015
public void laterRadioButtonChecked() {
    if(cors.equals(getString(R.string.undergraduate_traf))) {
        ectsPriceText.setText("250.00 kn");
        price = 250;
    } else {
        ectsPriceText.setText("200.00 kn");
        price = 200;
    }
}
```

P.S. There is no defined default values.

Comment: You mean to say that when you change item from dropdown list, program thinks you checked left radio however you checked right one?

Comment: @Lcukerd yes, exactly ... I've tried to fix it but without success

Comment: Why are you not using setOnCheckedChangeListener? Try it

Comment: @Lcukerd it's still the same ... every time when I change course, price variable and price text are the same, but now with onCheckedChange I've to change from left to right button and then again to left to see change for selected course

Comment: Seems like problem with your if statement. Try writing in log from if statements.

Comment: @Lcukerd It works now, but I think I have too much code ... after I initialised onCheckedChanged I had to write similar if statement for selecting different RB for different course from the list